# Exit from HttpClient session

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

How to exit from HttpClient session?

I use the following code to login to the application using Apache HttpClient

```
public HttpClient loginToHexgen(String username, String password) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // send post url to login to  hexgen
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check");

        try {
            // set the user name and password
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", password));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                post.abort();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return client;
    }
```

like the following :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client= httpRequest.loginToHexgen("mayank", "hexgen");
```

here `httpRequest` is the class where the `loginToHexgen` method is used.

If I want to login to the system with multiple user with diffrent user name and password how to do this?.

Like for example in the same session I want to logout one user and login using other user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a workaround – to send a request to a new user with a new cookieStore.

```
// Create a local instance of cookie store
cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
// Set the store
httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

Server will open a new session to your new user. Please note that the old session will NOT be closed.
I do not recommend to use this way.

The session management is performed on the server side – you can not do it on the client side.
I recommend in the end of your test you should call to a server URL that will invalidate a session on the server side.
(Generally applications that use Form authentication have a logout functionality and you just need to use it)

Comment: +1 for the answer, i have tried to send different user with different password but to my surprise it was not creating any issue and worked as i indented. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: The issue that you have the following code in your `loginToHexgen` function: `HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();`.
It is equal to the creation of cookieStore for a new user.
Notes: 1. If you will want to access URL on the behalf of the authenticated user you need to use the same HttpClient instance (otherwise request will be without cooikies).  2. You can check in your server and you will see that each login a new session is created.